# How can I switch from forward to backward in Interactive search/replace regex in Vim?

Tags: vim

For example I have some text:

```
    'y'     to substitute this match
    'l'     to substitute this match and then quit ("last")
    'n'     to skip this match
    <Esc>   to quit substituting
    'a'     to substitute this and all remaining matches {not in Vi}
    'q'     to quit substituting {not in Vi}
```

and by `:%s/substitute/sub/gc` I can interactively search/replace. If I press 'n' it goes to the next matched pattern, how can I undo 'n'? or search backwards?

In usual search mode `/search_word` we can skip by 'n' and 'N' is there something similar for substitute - `:%s/substitute/sub/gc` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mathias Bergert's answer does the trick, if you just need do simple single word replacement, and the replacement text is always fixed. Well perhaps this is satisfied with 70% of our daily editing. If you need the power of `s/.../.../` for your substitution needs, it may be not sufficient. For example, multiple words replacement, the back reference or the function expressions in the replacement part.

What I can think of is, first do a:

```
:s/substitute/sub/c
```

**note**, without `% range` and `g` flag.

then you just:

- press `n` or `N` for for/backwards search,
- if you think the match should be replaced, press `&`,
- if you did some mistake, press `u`

The key is, `&` will redo last substitution.

In this way, you can do more complex substitutions, which is hard for the simple `cw` like:

- `s/f../&, /`  add a comma after all `fxx` words (foo, far, fur...)
- `s/\v(foo)(\d+)/\=submatch(1).(submatch(2)+1)/` increment number after `foo`
- and so on...

Comment: tx, This is actually easier for me than the . command *(using azerty kbd)*

Answer (score 6):

Personally I prefer the [`.` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7325105/52598) over the substitute c flag, this adds much more flexibility.

Do something like this:

```
/substitute<cr>
cwsub<esc>
```

Search for "substitute", then `cw` (change word) to "sub" (`<esc>` exits insert mode)

Now you can use `n` and `N` to move and the dot `.` command to replace the "substitute" to "sub". With `u` you can even undo the last one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: For more complex searches use the `gn` motion. See `:h gn` and [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode: [Operating on search matches using gn](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/operating-on-search-matches-using-gn/)

Comment: Note, you can do /pattern<cr>cgn<replacement><esc> and then it is enough to only use '.' to jump to the next occurence and change it at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I made a plugin some time ago just for this. It's more extensive than the other answers so if you're ok with plugins you might like it

https://github.com/sosmo/vim-easyreplace

Basically, it executes your substitution on each match one by one when you press ctrl-n.