# How does the dot command work in this case?

Tags: vim

I was trying to figure out how the dot command works from an example from the book Practical Vim by Drew Neil.

---

Take the following bit of text:

```
var foo = "method("+argument1+","+"argument2"+")";
```

If the cursor is on the first + character, and we do the sequence:

```
s[space]+[space][Esc]
```

we add padding around the first +. i.e. the result is:

```
var foo = "method(" + argument1+","+"argument2"+")";
```

---

If we then move to the next + and use the dot command, we end up with:

```
var foo = "method(" + argument1 + ","+"argument2"+")";
```

I understand that Vim saves the text we type while in Insert mode until we exit to Normal mode, and then we can apply that change with the dot command.

But why does Vim save the deletion of the + that is done with the s command? Is it because the s command puts Vim in Insert mode first, and then deletes the character?

---

EDIT:
I checked the Vim documentation for the s command, and it says:

> Delete character and start insert.

So it sounds like it deletes the character, *then* goes into Insert mode, which would disprove my previous theory. What's going on!?

Comment: Comment rather than an answer here as I'm not sure this is where your confusion lies: the `.` command can repeat more than the last insert. For example, kill a line with `dd` and then `.` -- boom! next line is gone. So the "change" you're repeating starts with the mode change `s` (which also deletes the char under the cursor) and continues until you exit back to normal mode. That is what is repeated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dot command repeats the **last change**. This is **not** limited to changes in `INSERT` mode

To learn more,

```
:help change.txt
```

In this case, as @Two-Bit Alchemist has pointed out, everything happened from pressing <kbd>s</kbd> to the point when you return to `NORMAL` mode is a **change**

A good thing about dot command is that it can be extended to repeat multiple changes
Tim Pope's [vim-repeat](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat) is a good example of exploiting such possibilities.

Please refer to the following links to learn more
[what can the dot command repeat, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566235/what-can-the-dot-command-repeat-exactly)
[can someone explain to me why the dot command is so useful in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325052/can-someone-explain-to-me-why-the-dot-command-is-so-useful-in-vim)

Comment: Good link on `:help change.txt`. I couldn't find that for the life of me yesterday.